# Getting warning message while creating index in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2012

I have table which contains two columns. When I tried to create index for the `NVARCHAR(2000)` column, it is showing warning message like:

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes

But the index was created for this table in SQL Server:

```
Create Table Test
(
     Id Int primary key,
     ProdName Nvarchar(2000)
)
```

Inserted 1 million records.

```
Created index ix_Test on Test(ProdName)
```

Will SQL Server use this index on the `ProdName` column in `where` condition? Because it created with warning message.

Usually does the `Like` operator not use the index?

Comment: Do you really need an index on an `nvarchar(2000)`? If you're really going to have values that long then you might want to look at a full text index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating index SQL Server is checking column's metadata. Maximum index length for SQL Server 2012 is 900 bytes and for SQL Server 2016(1700 bytes).

For `NVARCHAR(2000)` maximum size in bytes is 4000 and it exceeds index's maximum limit.

```
Create Table Test(Id Int primary key,ProdName Nvarchar(2000));
INSERT INTO Test VALUES (1, REPLICATE('0123456789',45));
Create index ix_Test ON Test(ProdName);
INSERT INTO Test VALUES (2, REPLICATE('0123456789',46));
-- Operation failed. The index entry of length 920 bytes for the index    
--'ix_Test' exceeds the maximum length of 900 bytes.
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=e833e5e8e5dacb2b3937393b5eca5972)**

> Warning! The maximum key length is **900 bytes.** The index 'ix_Test' has maximum length of 4000 bytes. **For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.**

---

It means that inside your column you have string values that are shorter than 450 characters(900 bytes).

```
SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(ProdName))
FROM Test;
-- should be lower than 900
```

---

As for second question index will be used as long as condition is [SARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable):

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE ProductName = 'ABC' -- index usage;

SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE ProductName = 'AB%'; -- index usage

SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE ProductName LIKE '%B%'; -- no index seek, index/table scan instead
```

Comment: Thank you .For the first question,index is created for the table with warning message.so will it not use this index for this column value searching in where condition?Am i Correct?

Comment: @Ram It will use indexes for SARGable condition. Simply you won't be able to create index or insert/update for string that are longer than 450 characters.

Comment: fine print note: A condition like `... where Foo like '%Bar%'` will not result in an index _seek_, but may benefit from an index _scan_. More complex conditions, e.g. `... where ShoeSize = '9EEE' and Foo like '%Bar%'` might benefit from more complex indexes, e.g. an index on `ShoeSize` including `Foo` or a _covering index_. Hence, "no index usage" may be a little harsh.

Comment: @HABO Yes, you are right. Query would run a bit faster. Of course not as fast as with index seek but always a small gain is better than none :)